# How much space For ubuntu dde do I need for my work

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have SDD hard (128GB) tow partition, (C) for windows 10, and (D) for app data I want to install Ubuntu along with side windows 10
My programs used (Android Studio Davinci resolve Inkscape gimp chrome Netbeans...) and other light programe
Note: (D) Driver for Appdata Ex: DavinciResolve Cache and data Android Studio (Data, SKD, Gradle...) ...and other programs data are present on (D) driver and I have HDD Hard I present my data(videos, images, sounds....) on it

My question: How much space For ubuntu do I need for my work?

Comment: Ubuntu DDE is not an official Ubuntu flavor and is thus not supported here (see the [help/on-topic] for details). You may want to ask about this somewhere Ubuntu DDE is supported, such as [unix.se]. Three of the five close votes here were to close it as opinion-based rather than off-topic, though. I am somewhat disinclined to think this really opinion-based, but If you do post this somewhere Ubuntu DDE is supported, you may want to give even more details about how you are going to be using the system. That may help to get more reliable and objective answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is very subjective as it depends on how many third-party apps you install. The Ubuntu operating system itself is quite small. The bulk of space consumed are the included applications in a default install. In general, I recommend that people have a dedicated OS drive, eg: 128GB at a minimum, and then have a separate larger drive for data (in this case, you'd setup /home to point to that second drive).

Comment: thanks for you, is 25GB for (/)root Enough ?

Comment: Again, I don't know your use requirements. As little as 8GB can be more than enough for some people, but this actually won't give you enough space to upgrade to the next Ubuntu release in a standard install.

If you want a general recommendation, I'm going to say nothing less than 40GB, but this is also why I recommend people get a cheap 128GB drive to use just for the OS and mount /home, /opt and maybe even /var to separate larger drive.